How to prevent lag when moving a Circle with an AnimationTimer in JavaFX?
I have a problem with AnimationTimer class i use it to move Circle(ball).
When I run the program (is a pong game) the ball stopped for a moment (0.5-1 second) and then continued its movement (ball movement so laggy)
this is the main controller class
package com.anas.pong;

import javafx.animation.AnimationTimer;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class MainController implements Initializable {
    private enum MoveTo {
        bottomLeft,
        topLeft,
        topRight,
        bottomRight
    }
    private MoveTo where;
    private Circle ball;
    int ballX, ballY;


    @FXML
    private AnchorPane mainPane;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {

        // setting the ball
        ball = new Circle();
        ball.setRadius(13);
        ball.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        ball.setFill(Color.BLACK);

        // setting position of the ball
        ball.setLayoutX(400);
        ballX = 400;
        ball.setLayoutY(300);
        ballY = 300;

        mainPane.getChildren().add(ball);

        where = MoveTo.bottomLeft;

        AnimationTimer movement = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long l) {
                // moving to ...
                if (where.equals(MoveTo.bottomLeft))
                    bottomLeftMovement();
                else if (where.equals(MoveTo.topLeft))
                    topLeftMovement();
                else if (where.equals(MoveTo.topRight))
                    topRightMovement();
                else if (where.equals(MoveTo.bottomRight))
                    bottomRightMovement();
                else {
                    System.out.println("Nothing");
                    stop();
                }
            }
        };

        movement.start();
    }

    private void bottomLeftMovement() {

        // go bottom
        ball.setTranslateY(ball.getTranslateY()+2);
        ballY += 2;

        // go left
        ball.setTranslateX(ball.getTranslateX()-2);
        ballX -= 2;

        if (ballY >= 600-13)
            where = MoveTo.topLeft;

        else if (ballX <= 13) // 0+13
            where = MoveTo.bottomRight;

    }

    private void topLeftMovement() {
        ball.setTranslateY(ball.getTranslateY()-2);
        ballY -= 2;

        ball.setTranslateX(ball.getTranslateX()-2);
        ballX -= 2;

        if (ballX <= 13) // 0+13
            where = MoveTo.topRight;

        else if (ballY <= 13) // 0+13
            where = MoveTo.bottomLeft;

    }

    private void topRightMovement() {
        ball.setTranslateY(ball.getTranslateY()-2);
        ballY -= 2;

        ball.setTranslateX(ball.getTranslateX()+2);
        ballX += 2;

        if (ballX >= 800-13)
            where = MoveTo.topLeft;

        else if (ballY <= 13)
            where = MoveTo.bottomRight;

    }

    private void bottomRightMovement() {
        ball.setTranslateY(ball.getTranslateY()+2);
        ballY += 2;

        ball.setTranslateX(ball.getTranslateX()+2);
        ballX += 2;

        if (ballY >= 600-13)
            where = MoveTo.topRight;

        else if (ballX >= 800-13)
            where = MoveTo.bottomLeft;

    }
}


the ball should stay in the window of (800,600) and that works but sometimes the ball stopped for (0.5-1 second), I think the problem from the AnimationTimer class but I have tried TranslateTransition and Thread(with while (true)) and both of them has the same issue (lag in the movement).

JavaFX methods are only allowed to be called in one special thread:  the JavaFX Application Thread.  JavaFX creates this thread;  to run your own code on that thread, use Platform.runLater in the body of the Runnable you pass to your CompletableFuture.  You could also call the setOnFinished method of a PauseTransition, in which case Platform.runLater would not be necessary.

Using CompletableFuture is probably a bad idea. See if you can get some ideas from this .

This is not Swing, removed swing tag.

What is Countdown?  There is no code for it.  Whatever it is, it is likely wrong.  PauseTransition suggested by VGR would likely suffice, but I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish and your issue.  Whatever the issue, it is most likely with your code and not the JavaFX framework.

Countdown class extends AnimationTimer, i have tried to add Platform.run like this
completableFuture.thenRun(() -> Platform.runLater(() ->  {...
but it doesn't make any change

@Slaw done, you can try it now.

Almost a [mre]. You didn't provide the FXML file nor the application class. Though I doubt FXML is necessary to reproduce the problem (i.e., your example could probably be a single class, the one that extends Application, without FXML). That said, after I added the infrastructure so your code can run, it seems to work perfectly fine. I don't see any pause in the circle's animation and the animation does not lag. Which version of Java and JavaFX are you using? Which OS are you using?

Also, I've edited your question's title to be more accurate to your actual question. Let me know if I made a mistake; or you can undo the edit/apply your own edit.

The OP code makes everything so much more complicated than necessary.  A PauseTransition set to play itself in its onFinished Property will handle the looping animation.
It's also probably cleaner to use Node.layoutX and Node.layoutY than Node.translateX and Node.translateY, even though it won't make much difference when the Node is just left at [0,0] and then translated.
The direction Enum would be more useful if it also had fields for the x and y deltas to be applied, but it's actually completely unnecessary.  The ball will always have both an X and a Y delta (in this case both +- 2.0) and they simple invert when the walls are reached.  The logic for wall collision is the same whatever the current values of the X and Y delta are.
And there's no use for FXML or an AnchorPane when the layout is essentially non-existent.  So a simple Pane will work just fine, and the Circle is just added in code, as it was in the OP.
Here's a version in Kotlin (all of the JavaFX ideas are the same in Kotlin):
class Pong : Application() {
    override fun start(stage: Stage) {
        stage.scene = Scene(createContent(), 800.0, 600.0)
        stage.show()
    }

    private fun createContent() = Pane().apply {
        val ballX: DoubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(400.0)
        val ballY: DoubleProperty = SimpleDoubleProperty(300.0)
        var moveX = -2.0
        var moveY = -2.0
        children += Circle(13.0).apply {
            layoutXProperty().bind(ballX)
            layoutYProperty().bind(ballY)
        }
        val animation = PauseTransition(Duration.millis(10.0)).apply {
            setOnFinished {
                ballX.value += moveX
                ballY.value += moveY
                if ((ballX.doubleValue() > (800 - 13) || (ballX.doubleValue() < 13))) {
                    moveX *= (-1)
                }
                if ((ballY.doubleValue() > (600 - 13) || (ballY.doubleValue() < 13))) {
                    moveY *= (-1)
                }
                playFromStart()
            }
        }
        animation.play()
    }
}

fun main() = Application.launch(Pong::class.java)

This will run, and the ball bounces happily around the Pane without any hesitation or jerkiness.

Personally, I would use the centerX / centerY properties, but I suppose it doesn't really matter.

Also, just wondering, does the OP's code lag for you? Because it doesn't for me, which indicates this may be a problem with their system rather than the code.

@Slaw I never tried to run it, mostly because the FXML stuff was missing and I cannot bring myself to write any FXML - there is already too much of it in the world.  CenterX/Y never occurred to me, as rarely mess about with shapes.

@DaveB, i was using ubuntu 24.04 and i run the OP code in both Xorg and Wayland in hyprland and gnome and there's no difference the same problem, now i moved to endeavorOS and I'm still configuring it. I will reply later when i try both the OP code and the code you provide in the new OS. (Sorry for bad English)

@DaveB it works thanks.
the problem wasn't from my OS or display protocol(linux stuff) i think it was from the setTranslate methode
